# Using MySQL CASE statement with temporary variable, and CASE result is incorrect?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have a sample company HR database, where the tables employees and jobs.

```
employees
job_id name salary

jobs
job_id job_title
```

And my goal is to output a table with each job title and the number of employees in that job title, and the average salary of each job so the table looks something like this:

```
Job Title  Number of Employees  Average Salary  Range
```

And this is my current SQL code:

```
SELECT j.job_title AS 'Job Title', 
       COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Employees', 
       @averageSalary := ROUND(AVG(e.salary), 0) AS 'Average Salary',
       CASE 
           WHEN @averageSalary BETWEEN 0 AND 5000 THEN 'Low'
           WHEN @averageSalary BETWEEN 5001 AND 10000 THEN 'Medium'
           WHEN @averageSalary > 10001 THEN 'High'
       ELSE 'N/A' END AS 'Range'
FROM employees AS e
JOIN jobs AS j ON e.job_id = j.job_id
GROUP BY e.job_id;
```

And I get an output which is:

```
Job Title Number of Employees Salary Range
'Public Accountant', '1', '8300', 'High'
'Accounting Manager', '1', '12000', 'Medium'
'Administration Assistant', '1', '4400', 'High'
'President', '1', '24000', 'Low'
```

This is obviously wrong because according to the CASE statement I have, The Public Accountant's range should be 'Medium'. And I'm not sure why this is wrong. Obviously, I don't get any error, so I've been just searching for CASE result wrong, but I cannot seem to find something that helps me to understand what is going on.

What am I doing wrong? Where in my syntax is generating different outputs? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't really use variables like that. Variables in SQL are meant to be used to maintain state _between_ queries in a batch, not to hold temporary data within a query. That's what derived-tables are for. (there are exceptions, like concatenating a string or as a terrible substitute for `ROW_NUMBER` but I like to think those days are long behind us since MySQL 8 came out).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using variables like that is tricky, because the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` clause is undefined. You cannot tell before hand if the variable will be assigned before of after the `case` expression is evaluated.

You can either repeat the expression, or use a subquery:

```
select j.job_title, e.*,
        case 
            when e.average_salary between 0 and 5000 then 'low'
            when e.average_salary between 5001 and 10000 then 'medium'
            when e.average_salary > 10001 then 'high'
            else 'n/a' 
        end as salary_range
from (
    select job_id, 
        count(*) as number_of_employees, 
        round(avg(salary), 0) as average_salary
    from employees
    group by job_id
) e
inner join jobs j on j.job_id = e.job_id
```

Comment: Personally I'd do the `INNER JOIN jobs` in the outer-query rather than the inner-query - as the current query depends on MySQL's looser (i.e. incorrect) `GROUP BY with-unrelated-columns` support.